# (iOS)Why backButtonTitle change to "Back" after WkWebView didFinish navigation?

Tags: ios, swift

I set my first viewcontroller's title to "Main", and push a new viewcontroller contains a WkWebView, then I can see the backButtonTitle is "Main", that's what I wanted.

But if I navigate to another address inside the webview, I see the backButtonTitle change to default title "Back", I try change the title to "Main" in didFinish navigation：

```
navigationItem.backButtonTitle="Main"
```

but does not work at all!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an initializer

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Main", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```